# Assign the value to a two-dimensional array in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider:

```
List<List<StyleModel>> listofSubstyles=[[]];
final List<StyleModel> _subStyle =<StyleModel> [];
listofSubstyles.add(_subStyle);
```

My array is dynamic and I want to add data like this:

```
listofSubstyles[index].add(_subStyle);
```

But it's showing an error: value is out of range.

Entering data into a two-dimensional array shows errors.

Comment: It basically mean that you are trying to assign to index which is not there. So, please share what's inside list and what's the value of index.

Comment: yes you are right but I want the index to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Solution:**

Change

```
List<List<StyleModel>> listofSubstyles = [[]];
```

to

```
List<List<StyleModel>> listofSubstyles = [];
```

---

**Problem:**

During initialization `List<List<StyleModel>> listofSubstyles=[[]]` this initialises the `listofSubstyles` with a single empty list, meaning using `listofSubstyles[index]` to retrieve an element at a particular index will only be successful if index is equal to `0` else error will be thrown.

Updated code:

```
List<List<StyleModel>> listofSubstyles = [];
final List<StyleModel> _subStyle = <StyleModel> [];
listofSubstyles.add(_subStyle);

// add a new empty sublist
listofSubstyles.add([]);

// add data to the sublist at index 1
listofSubstyles[1].add(_subStyle);
```